# Is it possible to prove simply by manipulation that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^2\bigl(2-e^{-i/x}-e^{i/x}\bigr)=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, limits-without-lhopital

In fact, it turns out that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\left(2-e^{-z/x}-e^{z/x}\right)=-z^2$$ for any complex $z$. What is a simple (no DLH, Taylor, Maclaurin, ...) and "primitive" (*no using directly or indirectly notable trigonometric limits, namely* $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos^z x}{x}=z/2$) approach to this problem? I'm asking out of curiosity, after doing some homework related to, indeed, notable limits, and derivatives. Unfortunately I couldn't do much, thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that it is minus the square of $x(e^{-z/(2x)}-e^{z/(2x)})$

Answer (score 3):

It holds that
$$
x^2(2-e^{-z/x}-e^{z/x}) = -x^2(e^{z/(2x)}-e^{-z/(2x)})^2=-z^2\Bigl(\frac{\sinh(z/(2x))}{z/2x}\Bigr)^2.
$$
Are you allowed to use that $\frac{\sinh t}{t}\to 1$ as $t\to 0$, then this is finished... If not, then I must ask you: What are you allowed to use?

Comment: Among the notable limits, only those not deriving from the ones I've just specified in the OP.

Comment: If you know that the derivative of $\sinh t$ is $\cosh t$, then, since $\sinh 0=0$ and $\cosh 0=1$, $\sinh t/t=(\sinh t-\sinh 0)/t\to \cosh 0=1$ as $t\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$(2-e^{-i/x}-e^{i/x})=2-(2 cos{\frac{1}{x}})$

but $cos{\frac{1}{x}}=\dfrac{1-(\tan{\frac{1}{2x}})^2}{1+(\tan{\frac{1}{2x}})^2}$

Then you have

$(2-e^{-i/x}-e^{i/x})=\dfrac{4(\tan{\frac{1}{2x}})^2}{1+(\tan{\frac{1}{2x}})^2}$

Can we finish here with your limitations?

Comment: Does this use $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}$? If so, it's not what I'm looking for. Anything using directly or indirectly the notable limits I've just specified in the OP does not fit my limitations, which, perhaps, make it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\left(2-e^{-z/x}-e^{z/x}\right)= \lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\left[-\left(e^{z/2x}-e^{-z/2x}\right)^2\right] \\ = \lim_{x\to\infty} -x^2\left(2\sinh\left(\frac{z}{2x}\right)\right)^2 \\ =  \lim_{x\to\infty} -\left(2x\sinh\left(\frac{z}{2x}\right)\right)^2$$ I'm not sure what your limitations are from here on out, but if you can now show that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}2x\sinh\left(\frac{z}{2x}\right)=z$$ then it'll follow pretty easily.

Comment: I haven't dealt with hypergeometric functions yet, does $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sinh x}{x}=1$ derive from $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Comment: I would guess yes since the two types of trig functions share much in common, but I haven't worked extensively with hypergeometric functions either. Perhaps you could establish that as a lemma before you move on to your limit problem? I imagine the lemma would come very easily by a Taylor Series expansion of $\sinh$.

Comment: Not really, thanks for the suggestion but I'd like the problem to be solved without referring in any way to those limits I've just specified in the OP. Which might be impossible, I guess.

Comment: I see. I was hoping you could use those limits in the Lemma. How about the squeeze theorem?

Comment: If the bounding functions don't use those limits it would be great.

Comment: I suppose you could make cases. If $\Re\{z\}=0$ then you can write the complex exponent strictly in terms of sine and get the result easily with the squeeze theorem. If $\Re\{z\} \neq 0$ then things are trickier.

Comment: If it is necessary, when I have time I'll try following your hint, now I have to get back to my homework, thanks again.